# UI path Robot Manager

Tags: rpa, uipath, uipath-robot

Is `UiPath robot tool` available with free `UiPath Community Edition`?

I tried using `UiPath Studio` and `Orchestrator` but I'm unable to see my published files on `Orchestrator`, because `UiPath Robot` is not there on my system. Does is require license or full purchase of the tool ?
If yes, how to buy the license?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a orchestrator requires license activation and for purchasing a license you can refer to this link.

https://studio.uipath.com/docs/activating-your-studio-license-locally

A license on a Robot can be activated:

While installing the Robot by using the CODE parameter. For example:
D:\UiPathPlatform.msi CODE=1234567890

After the installation is done, using the /email and /code. For example:
C:\Program Files (x86)\UiPath\Studio\UiPath\regutil.exe activate /code=1234567890

Answer (score 2):

With UiPath Studio 2017.1.6522 you can find the robot.exe here:

C:\Users\YOUR_USER_ACCOUNT\AppData\Local\UiPath\app-17.1.6522\Ui-Robot.exe

or start it in CMD in the same folder with:

> C:\Users\YOUR_USER_ACCOUNT\AppData\Local\UiPath\app-17.1.6522\Ui-Robot.exeUiRobot.exe /tray

The /tray also shows the icon in the taskbar